# How To handle Dynamic textBoxes within dynamic table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, findcontrol, dynamic-controls

I want to SUM UP(add) values from textboxes in same columns and display SUM to last row Textboxes respectively on click of "Calculate" Button
All the textboxes are generated dynamically on click of “Create table”  button. 
I am not getting how to get the ID’s of these textboxes.

Code of .aspx file is as follows :

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    Select CC No :&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="100px">
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Create Table" 
        style="height: 26px" Width="100px" />
```

Code Goes like this for Dynamic table n textboxes in aspx.cs file:

```
public partial class stable : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private int tblRow;
private int tblCol = 9;
private int i, j;
private bool CTflag;

Table table = new Table();
TableRow row,rrow;
TableCell cell,rcell;
FileUpload fileUp;
Button UpLdButton;
TextBox tb,tbr;
TextBox txtRes; // to store result of calculation

string cmdArg; // for passing filuploaders id with Command button
string txtArgs;

private string filename = "fileUpLoader";

private string tbRowId = "row";
private string tbColId = "col";

protected int Rows
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["Rows"] != null ? (int)ViewState["Rows"] : 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Rows"] = tblRow;
    }
}

// Columns property to hold the Columns in the ViewState
protected int Columns
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["Columns"] != null ? (int)ViewState["Columns"] : 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Columns"] = tblCol;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Rows = tblRow;
        this.Columns = tblCol;
        if (CTflag == false)
        {
            CreateDynamicTable();
        }
        else
        {
            CTflag = true;
        }
    }
    //LoadViewState(object this);
    //CreateDynamicTable();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Button1.Visible = false;
    CreateDynamicTable();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateDynamicTable();
}

protected void CreateDynamicTable()
{
    //Button1.Visible = false;
    tblRow = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
    //Creat the Table and Add it to the Page    
    if (CTflag == false)
    {
        //Table table = new Table();
        table.Caption = "Challan Entry";
        table.ID = "Challan Entry";
        table.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BurlyWood;
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(table);

        // Now iterate through the table and add your controls
        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            row = new TableRow();
            row.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;

            for (j = 0; j <= tblCol; j++)
            {
                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.BorderWidth = 5;
                cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;
                cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
                for (j = 0; j <= tblCol; j++)
                {
                    string[] Header = { "CC NO.", "DATE", "TotalAmt", "NoOfRecpt", "Energy", "New", "Theft", "Misc", "SelectFile", "Upload", "Status" };
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = "lblHeader" + j;
                    if (j == 8)
                    {
                        lbl.Width = 220;
                    }
                    else if (j == 9)
                    {
                        lbl.Width = 50;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl.Width = 100;
                    }
                    lbl.Text = Header[j];

                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

            // Add the TableRow to the Table
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < tblRow; i++)
        {
            row = new TableRow();
            row.ID = tbRowId + i;
            row.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;

            for (j = 0; j <= tblCol; j++)
            {
                cell = new TableCell();
                cell.ID = tbColId + i + j;
                cell.BorderWidth = 5;
                cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;
                cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
                for (j = 0; j <= 0; j++)
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = "lblCCRow" + i + "Col" + j;
                    lbl.Text = "CC NO. " + i + " ";
                    lbl.Width = 100;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                for (j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = "lblRow" + i + "Col" + j;
                    lbl.Width = 100;
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Day) + "/" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Month) + "/" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year);
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                for (j = 2; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    tb = new TextBox();
                    tb.Width = 100;
                    tb.ID = "txtBoxRow" + i + "Col" + j;

                    tb.Text = "";
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
                }
                for (j = 8; j <= 8; j++)
                {
                    fileUp = new FileUpload();
                    //m = i; n = j;
                    fileUp.ID = filename + i + j;
                    fileUp.Width = 220;
                    cell.Controls.Add(fileUp);
                    cmdArg = fileUp.ID;

                    UpLdButton = new Button();
                    UpLdButton.Width = 100;
                    UpLdButton.Text = "Upload" + i + "Col" + j;
                    UpLdButton.ID = UpLdButton.Text;
                    UpLdButton.CommandArgument = cmdArg;
                    cell.Controls.Add(UpLdButton);

                    UpLdButton.Click += new EventHandler(UpLdButton_Click);
                }
                for (j = 9; j <= 9; j++)
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = "lblRow" + i + "Col" + j;
                    lbl.Text = "[ Status ]";
                    lbl.Width = 100;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

            // Add the TableRow to the Table
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        } //outer for-loop end

        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            rrow = new TableRow();
            rrow.ID = "ResultRow";
            rrow.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;

            for (j = 0; j <= tblCol; j++)
            {
                rcell = new TableCell();
                rcell.ID = "resultCol" + j;
                rcell.BorderWidth = 5;
                rcell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Ridge;
                rcell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Azure;
                for (j = 0; j <= 0; j++)
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    //lbl.ID = "lblCCRow" + i + "Col" + j;
                    lbl.Text = "<b>Total</b>";
                    lbl.Width = 100;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    rcell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                for (j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    //lbl.ID = "lblRow" + i + "Col" + j;
                    lbl.Width = 100;
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Day) + "/" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Month) + "/" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Year);
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    rcell.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                for (j = 2; j <= 7; j++)
                {
                    tbr = new TextBox();
                    tbr.Width = 100;
                    tbr.ID = "txtResult" + j;

                    tbr.Text = tbr.ID;
                    // Add the control to the TableCell
                    rcell.Controls.Add(tbr);
                }
                for (j = 8; j <= 8; j++)
                {
                    Button btnCal = new Button();
                    btnCal.Width = 100;
                    btnCal.Text = "Calculate";
                    btnCal.ID = btnCal.Text;
                    txtArgs = tb.ID;
                    btnCal.CommandArgument = txtArgs;
                    Label1.Text = txtArgs;
                    rcell.Controls.Add(btnCal);
                    btnCal.Click += new EventHandler(btnCal_Click);
                }

                rrow.Cells.Add(rcell);
            }

            // Add the TableRow to the Table
            table.Rows.Add(rrow);
        }

        //flag seetting
        CTflag = true;
        ViewState["dynamictable"] = true;
    }
}
void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Calculation part goes here        
}
protected override void LoadViewState(object earlierState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(earlierState);
    if (ViewState["dynamictable"] == null)
        CreateDynamicTable();
}

void UpLdButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnUpLD = sender as Button;
    btnUpLD = (Button)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(UpLdButton.ID);
    //btnUpLD.Text = Convert.ToString((Button)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(UpLdButton.ID));
    //FileUpload fileupld = new FileUpload();
    fileUp = (FileUpload)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(fileUp.ID);
    string args = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
    lblTest.Text = args;
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CreateDynamicTable();
    Label1.Text = "Index Changed!!!";
}
```

}

following code is what i have tried ... bt it's faulty.
while reading textBox ID's m only getting the last textBox ID only and i am unale to 
iterate trough textBox Id's

```
void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnCalculate = sender as Button;
    TextBox txtFields;   // Resultant txtField        
    string[,] txtNames = new string[tblRow,6];

    double TotAmt = new double();
    double NoOfRect = new double();
    double Energy = new double();
    double New1 = new double();
    double Theft = new double();
    double Misc = new double();

    TotAmt = 0; NoOfRect = 0; Energy = 0; New1 = 0; Theft = 0; Misc = 0;



    for (int i = 0; i < tblRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 7; j++)
        {
            txtRes = new TextBox();
            //txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
            //txtFields.Text = txtFields.ID;
            //txtNames[i,j] = txtFields.Text;
            if (j == 2)
            {
                txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
                txtNames[i, j] = txtFields.Text;
                TotAmt+= Convert.ToDouble(txtNames[i, j]);
                txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
                txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(TotAmt);
            }
            else if (j == 3)
            {
                txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
                txtNames[i, j] = txtFields.Text;
                NoOfRect+= Convert.ToDouble(txtNames[i, j]);
                txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
                txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(NoOfRect);
            }
            else if (j == 4)
            {
                txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
                txtNames[i, j] = txtFields.Text;
                Energy += Convert.ToDouble(txtNames[i, j]);
                txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
                txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(Energy);
            }
            else if (j == 5)
            {
                txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
                txtNames[i, j] = txtFields.Text;
                New1 += Convert.ToDouble(txtNames[i, j]);
                txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
                txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(New1);
            }
            else if (j == 6)
            {
                txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
                txtNames[i, j] = txtFields.Text;
                Theft += Convert.ToDouble(txtNames[i, j]);
                txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
                txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(Theft);
            }
            else if (j == 7)
            {
                txtFields = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(row.ID).FindControl(cell.ID).FindControl(tb.ID);
                txtNames[i, j] = txtFields.Text;
                Misc += Convert.ToDouble(txtNames[i, j]);
                txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
                txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(Misc);
            }
            else 
            {
                Label1.Text = Convert.ToString("Value of J : " +j);
            }
            //txtRes = (TextBox)this.FindControl(Form.ID).FindControl(table.ID).FindControl(rrow.ID).FindControl(rcell.ID).FindControl(tbr.ID);
            //txtRes.Text = Convert.ToString(results[i, j]);
        }
    }
```

Plz suggest me correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a useful function. [Function source](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html)

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
        {
            return root;
        }

        foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
        {
            Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
            if (t != null)
            {
                return t;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Then Just loop for the text boxes like this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tblRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j <= 7; j++)
            {
                TextBox tb = FindControlRecursive(this, string.Format("txtBoxRow{0}Col{1}", i, j));
                switch(j)
                {
                    case 2:
                        TotAmt += Convert.ToDouble(tb.Text);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                    default:
                        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString("Value of J : " + j);
                }
            }
        }
```